# Does the inverse of an $n \times n$ matrix with columns adding to 1 also have columns adding to 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How would I go about showing that the inverse of an $n \times n$ matrix with columns adding to one also has columns adding to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix all of whose columns sum to $1$. The condition is equivalent to $A^T\bf{1}=\bf{1}$, where $\bf{1}$ denotes the column vector of all ones. Multiplying through by the inverse transpose of $A$ yields ${\bf 1}=(A^{-1})^T\bf{1}$, which means that the inverse of $A$ satisfies the same condition, as desired.